# Regexp to extract studyinstanceuid from dump

Tags: regex

I need to capture numbers and dots between brackets on lines containing the string 0020,000d, for example:

```
I: (0020,000d) UI [1.2.410.200001.1104.20160720104648421 ] #  38, 1 StudyInstanceUID
```

Using this regexp `0020,000d.*\[([\.0-9]+)\]` I can match the needed value only if it doesn't have a space inside the brackets. How can I match the needed value ignoring any other character?.

**Edit**
If I use this regexp `0020,000d.*\[([\.0-9(\s|^\s))]+)\]` I can capture numbers and dots and/or spaces, now if the string contains a space how can I capture in a group everything but the space?.

To clarify, I want to extract the `1.2.410.200001.1104.20160720104648421` string.

Comment: Are you saying you want to match space? Just add a space to your character class, i.e. `[. 0-9]` (you don't need to escape a dot in a character class).

Comment: No, I want to ignore space, the value between brackets can contain them or not.

Comment: Then you just need to allow zero or more spaces after the numbers-and-dots sequence before the closing bracket: `0020,000d.*\[([.0-9]+) *\]`.

Comment: Great! this worked `0020,000d.*\[([\.0-9]+) *\]`. Please post it as an answer to let me mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codifying my (apparently helpful) answer from the comments:

You just need to allow zero or more spaces after the numbers-and-dots sequence before the closing bracket:

```
0020,000d.*\[([.0-9]+) *\]
```

Also, please note that you don't need to escape a dot in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let regex = /(?!\[)[.\d]+(?=[(\s)*\]])/g

let str = 'I: (0020,000d) UI [1.2.410.200001.1104.20160720104648421   ]'

let result = str.match(regex);

console.log(result);
```